# How do I persist data retrieved from PHP login between pages in jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, json

I made a login script in jQuery mobile and php. The php file sets a creates a session and sets $_SESSION['myusername']. Can I retrieve the username from the session variable from the loggedin.html page or do I have to do 'var myusername = data.username;' on the login page then somehow pass this var to the loggedin.html page.

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-type: application/json');

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$dbusername="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="testDB"; // Database name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$dbusername", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['username']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['password']; 

$sql="SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
    session_register("session_username");
    session_register("session_password"); 

    $id = $row["id"];   
    session_register('id'); 
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;

    session_register('username'); 
    $_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;

    mysql_query("UPDATE members SET last_log_date=now() WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1");
    }
$json = array('boolean' => true, 'jsonUser' => $_SESSION['username']);
echo json_encode($json);
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

EDIT:

```
var user="<?php echo $myusername; ?>";
$(document).ready(function(e) {

$('#usernamediv').html(user);
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good day!
As I see, you don't use any PHP-framework.
Try to use any, e.g. [Codeigniter](http://codeigniter.com), so you can put all $_SESSION into view inside regular variables. So you will not need any @session_start statement.

Answer (score 2):

You could just go like this:

```
<script language="javascript">
var username="<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>";
</script>
```

There's not reason you can't put echo PHP variables inside Javascript!

Comment: You've missed quotes PS: don't confuse newbies, it is not "PHP inside Javascript"

Comment: Oops! Javascript is not an everyday language for me. It's been fixed!

Comment: `window.username=<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['username']) ?>; ` makes it global and works with UTF-8 encoded strings.

Comment: I can`t get either of these to work, see edit. I`m testing locally right now but the release will be cross domain

Comment: You may need to do `session_start();`

Comment: I did add a session_start(); before I tried. I did a console.log(user); and got <?php echo $myusername; ?>